# Cura Initialize the Virtual Python Development Environment error

Tags: conan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubTNd.png)
when i build cura cliest for source ,i follow the guide from   "https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source#1-configure-conan",
my env :
win10
vs=2012
conan=1.60.2,
python=3.10.4

```
 run "conan install . --build=missing --update -o cura:devtools=True -g VirtualPythonEnv" get this error,how to solve it?

thanks for help


I tried the steps from the "https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source#1-configure-conan" untill Initialize the Virtual Python Development Environment ,i got the error
```

Comment: This question is badly formatted and seems incomplete. Please try to edit it, to make sure the details are clear, and the format is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.